# How to synchronize things

Tags: java

I have been wondering this forever. I don't know how things can happen at the same time.

I want to know how to sync in java without separate threads. For example, in a real video game how do things hapen at the same time without separate threads?
How would a person move two limbs at the same time in the game?
How could I do it in java?

Comment: As far as I know you can't, that is why we have Threads, because other stuff is sequential, so you have to wait for one operation to end before starting another...

Comment: I think i understand your forst comment now. It makes sense

Comment: 1) Draw both arms in different positions to an image that is used for the screen. 2) `repaint()`

Comment: That is only with a 2d game

Answer (score 1):

Generally they don't. Those kinds of updates in video games are usually performed all in one go, then all rendered at once, in a single frame. So there's a state update step, and then a rendering step.

In the update step, the positions of, for instance, the bones in the arms would be updated according to how they were supposed to move (perhaps in response to input received from a keyboard or mouse), then the whole scene is rendered again with the new positions.

Without threads, things just don't (technically) happen at exactly the same time. Frequently, the program will wait for input from something (a user, or the network, or just a timer that you've set to go off every 100 milliseconds), and while one part of the program is waiting for that, another part might run.

Those kinds of situations are generally event driven - have a look at the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for a guide on how you might approach that. You'll have something that waits for input, then fires the appropriate response events, which are "listened" to by any number of objects that are "waiting" for that event to happen.

This generally gives the appearance of things happening simultaneously, because you try to keep the code that runs on these events small - it's so quick you just can't tell the difference.

If you really want things running at the same time, however, you're just going to need to use threads (or get into graphics card programming - that's lots of fun :D)

Comment: That was very helpful. So the processor is way faster than rendering so the user cant notice anything.

Comment: @HarrisonBergeron Yes. Well, that depends on how much processing you're trying to do - if the processor is to slow or there's to much to do, it just doesn't draw as often. That's sometimes why you get frame-rate drops (other reasons are too much processing for the graphics card to do, which I think is probably usually more common)

Comment: Yep that makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard software architecture is a game loop. It is basically like this:

```
while the game is running
    for each object in the game
        check for interactions with other objects
        update the objects position
    draw the game state to a hidden surface
    copy the hidden surface to the screen
```